# Exporting Grid Data to Excel and saving it in zip format

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, zip, export-to-excel

Hi i'm working on asp net application. In this I need to Export Grid data to Excel and finally the excel file should be saved as zip file. I don't want to first save Excel file in some location then use zip functionality to fetch that file and convert it into Zip and save it. I want functionality which will directly convert Grid to Excel then Zip then finally saves it. I've seen so many forms and sites but none gave proper answer.

Comment: What version of excel are you targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by `dot.net` Zip dll And following code  will help you

```
gv.AllowPaging = false;
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileName);
            Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            gv.RenderControl(htw);
           // byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(somestring);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
             string attachment = sw.ToString();
             byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(attachment);
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);   // <-- must do this after writing the stream!
           //   File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\Saurabh\Testing\inputpdf\saurabhhtest.xls", stream.GetBuffer());



        using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile())
        {
            zipFile.AddEntry("saurabhtest1.xls", stream);
            zipFile.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        }
```